# Xamarin Portable keep keyboard open in an Entry

Tags: xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Protable project I have a Entry. What I want is, that after pressing "ok" on the numeric keyboard, the keyboard should not disappear, it should stay open until I press somewhere else on the screen. I used the `OnCompleted` trigger to set the `focus` again on the same Entry. It works but there is this little animation of the keyboard where it's disappearing and reopen again. I want that the keyboard should stay open without that animation. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the case that you do not need a done button here ?

Comment: I use a grid and in each cell is a label. For example: I'm in cell 1 and the value from the entry should be the text of the label in cell1. After hitting "ok" the next value in the entry will be the text of the label in cell 2 and so on. Hope you understand what I mean.